# WooCommerce REST API - DELETE PUT

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce REST API v3, and I am sending requests by Postman with `OAuth1.0 authorization`.

While sending `GET` or `POST` requests everything is OK, but when I am trying to send DELETE or `PUT` request I got a message :

> Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match

but creating signature algorithm are the same.

Any ideas ? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Server when I hosted my WordPress had disabled this methods probably. I tried another shop and everything works fine.